# E: Unable to locate package gradle

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, gradle, fuse

I am trying to run example filesystem of fuse-jna (https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna) . but it ask me to install gradle

```
syed@ubuntu:~/Downloads/fuse-jna-master/examples$ ./hellofs.sh ~/hellofs
gradle not found in $PATH. Please install gradle.
```

I have ubuntu 12 and I tried to install Gradle via `sudo apt-get install gradle` but I got the error

```
E: Unable to locate package gradle


syed@ubuntu:~/Downloads/fuse-jna-master/examples$ sudo apt-get install gradle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gradle
```

Please guide me how to solve the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thanks for the answers.

I have installed gradle by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/328178/gradle-in-13-04-ubuntu-launchpad-build

Answer (score 0):

Try http://gvmtool.net/. I'm using it on linux + mac.

It works very smoothly (not only for gradle), easy to switch versions, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is universe enabled on your system's apt system? The gradle package is in there:

```
$ apt-cache show gradle
Package: gradle
Priority: optional
Section: universe/java
...
```

Comment: I run ap-cache show gradle , it show me message as:
N: Unable to locate package gradle
E: No packages found

Comment: You need to enable the universe repository on your system then, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: Have you tried $ sudo apt-get update, then $ apt-cache show gradle? If that does not work, can you post your sources.list?